# What is the equivalent of a z-statistic for a textual variable containing discrete values?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have a variable in my data which contains discrete values which have no canonical order, e.g. `Apple, Orange, Pear`.

These values appear with a certain frequency in my base sample. I have a subset of my sample which contains the same variable, and I would like to provide a measure of the similarity of the `Fruit` variable between the subset and the overall sample.

For continuous variables I use the z-stat and Kolmogorov-Smirnov, and I am looking for something equivalent for my `Fruit` variable.

I have considered ordering the values in the original sample by their frequency of occurrence and faking a CDF and using K-S, but that feels like a hack. Well, it would be a hack...

I could also invent something that takes a weighted difference of the populations, but I would rather use a conventional statistic if such a thing exists.

Comment: in my searches I have come across the Bhattacharyya distance and Kullback-Leibler divergence. I think one of these might do the trick, but I am going to have a hard time explaining to my less statistically savvy audience what they mean. I am hoping I am missing something more obvious.

Comment: [The chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) works with categorial data.  Will that suit your purposes?

Answer (score 2):

For categorical data, you can use the [multinomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_test) with the null hypothesis parameters set to the base sample frequencies.

It will tell you how "unusual" your sample is if we assume it were drawn from the base sample.